# How to learn a Vandermonde matrix from data

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

<sub>Cross-posted on [Operations Research SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7391/estimation-of-vandermonde-matrix).</sub>

---

I would like to discuss how to tackle an optimization problem to learn a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). In particular, I have an optimization problem in the following form:

\begin{align}
V &= \operatorname{argmin}_{V}\|A -  \operatorname{diag}(Vb )C\|_F^2
\end{align}
where $A,C$ are $N \times N$ matrices, $V$ is a $N \times K$ Vandermonde matrix with $N >K$ and $b$ is a $K \times 1$ vector of coefficients.

This is a generalization of FIR filter design, where instead of finding the filter coefficients $b$ we search for the basis vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ of the Vandermonde matrix. Each of this vector is such that $v_{i+1}= v_i \odot v_1 $, i.e., it is a geometric progression over the rows.

How can I learn the matrix $V$? Is there a a way to rewrite such problem in a form easier to optimize?

The problem is not convex, since it is the composition of a norm with a non-affine mapping of the $N$ variables contained in $v_1$. Exploiting the relationship between Frobenius norm and trace property, I could arrive at the problem of minimizing $V$ over the function:

$$\operatorname{vec}(Z)^\top \operatorname{vec}(Z) -2 \operatorname{vec}(A)^{\top}\operatorname{vec}(Z) $$

where $\operatorname{vec}(Z)= \operatorname{vec}(C)^\top (I \odot I) \operatorname{vec}(Vb)$.
Might this help in solving for $V$? (or better, for $v_1$?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\h#1{{\odot #1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\SDiag#1{\operatorname{SubDiag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Construct a Vandermonde matrix $V$ from the
independent
vector $x$ as follows
$$\eqalign{
V &= \m{x^\h{0}&x^\h{\o}&x^\h{2}&x^{\odot 3}&\ldots&x^\h{(k-1)}}
     \;\in\bbR{n\times k} \\
  &= \m{\o&&x&&x^\h{2}&x^\h{3}&\ldots&x^\h{(k-1)}} \\
\\
x^{\odot 3} &= x\odot x\odot x
     \quad\quad\bR{{\rm Hadamard\;powers/products}} \\
dx^{\odot 3}
 &= \c{dx}\odot x\odot x
  + x\odot \c{dx}\odot x
  + x\odot x\odot \c{dx} \\
 &= 3x^\h{2}\odot {dx} \\
}$$
The differential of the matrix (wrt $x$) can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
dV
 &= \m{0&&\o&&2x^{\odot\o}&&3x^{\odot2}&\ldots}
    \odot \m{dx&dx&dx&\ldots} \\ 
 &= \bR{VD_k^T}\odot\bR{dx\,\o^T} \\ 
 &= \Diag{dx}\cdot \bR{VD_k^T} \\
D_k &= \SDiag{1,2,3,\ldots} = \m{
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\c{\o} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \c{2} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \c{3} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots \\
} \;\in\bbR{k\times k} \\ 
}$$
The $D_k$ matrix is the *Differentiation Matrix* for the polynomial space.

For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
M &= {\Diag{Vb}C-A} \\
H &= \diag{MC^T}\,b^T \\
}$$
Note that $H$ is a function of $M$ which is a function of $V$ which is a function of $x$.

Therefore everything $\big($except for $A,b,C,D_k\big)$ is a polynomial function of $x$.

Now write the cost function and calculate its differential
and gradient wrt $x$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \frac 12 M:M \\
d\phi &= M:dM \\
 &= M:\BR{\Diag{dV\,b}\,C} \\
 &= H:dV \\
 &= H:\LR{\Diag{dx}\cdot \bR{VD_k^T}} \\
 &= \LR{HD_k V^T}:\Diag{dx} \\
 &= \diag{HD_k V^T}:dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= \diag{HD_k V^T} \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
\\
}$$

---

Setting the gradient to zero yields a complicated system of (nonlinear) polynomial equations
$$\eqalign{ f(x) = 0 \;\in\bbR{n} }$$
whose roots must be found. Once the optimal $x$ has been located, the corresponding $V$ matrix can be constructed, as shown at the top of the post.

There will undoubtedly be many, many roots of $f(x),\,$ all of which are **local** extrema of the cost function. Each must be checked to determine if it's the desired **global** minimum.

Perhaps using a Computer Algebra System you can find the roots using a Gröbner basis or something.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. You mention that each local extrema must be checked for determining whether it is a global minimum... do you have any idea on how much complex is it solving this operation? I need to solve this problem multiple times since it is contained in an iterative routine (actually in my problem also b and C are unknowns, thus I apply an alternating minimization approach. Would you suggest other approaches in that case?). 
Also, I am using MATLAB/ Python... which CAS would you suggest for the purpose?

Comment: Also, which property did you use to go from the second equality to the third one (where you introduce the matrix $H$) in $d \phi$?

Comment: If you're using an ADMM approach and solving sequentially for the values of $(b,C,x)$, then you don't need the global minimum. Just accept the first root of $f(x)$ that your favorite NLE solver (e.g. `fsolve`, `roots`) converges to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Also with your updated answer, I did not directly see how the $H$ was introduced, but actually I just realized $A: Diag(b)= diag(A):b$.

Comment: Is it correct to say that if $M= \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} \operatorname{Diag}(V b_l)C_l$ then the sum will lead to $\partial \phi / \partial x = \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} \operatorname{diag}(H_l D_k V^\top)$, where $H_l= \operatorname{diag}(M C_l^\top) b_l^\top$?

Comment: In my code implementation, it seems that the cost function does not decrease with some gradient descent steps. However, it seems that using a minus sign for the gradient it works. Is a minus sign missing on your calculation?

Comment: @VanBaffo  A gradient descent method always steps in the direction of the **negative** gradient because that's the direction of the minimum.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I mean is that the cost decreases only if I take the negative of the negative gradient ( so with a minus on your computation).

Comment: The only opportunity for a sign flip is that I define $\,M = {\rm Diag}(Vb)\,C-A\;$ whereas in your problem statement you used $\|A-{\rm Diag}(Vb)\,C\|^2.\;$ You need to use my definition of $M\;$

Comment: Oh, yes, I used the function in my question, not following your definition. I thought was the same honestly. The sign flip is on your second line after $d \phi$ right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : Maybe it can help to consider $$\left[\begin{array}{lllll}1&0&0&0&0\\x&0&0&0&0\\0&x&0&0&0\\0&0&x&0&0\\0&0&0&x&0\end{array}\right]^4 = \left[\begin{array}{lllll}1&0&0&0&0\\x&0&0&0&0\\x^2&0&0&0&0\\x^3&0&0&0&0\\x^4&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

Together with regularization solving for a matrix with Kronecker products and some iterative / continuity approach.

Comment: I do not understand the point of this equation and how it is related to my question honestly :)

Comment: @Albus The first column is the first row in a Vandermonde matrix. The rest is just linearization and bookkeeping.

Comment: But what does the first matrix represent? And what does the second one? I do not see a Vandermonde matrix somewhere